# NetTrain always crashes in out of core training with NetEncoder Setting

Tags: bugs, machine-learning, neural-networks

See this official example [example](https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/neural-networks/out-of-core-image-classification.html?product=mathematica)

[image]

My enviroment is Windows 10 GTX1080 with Mathematica 11.1.1

It's Ok if I import all training images into memory.

Even in the simple case`NetTrain[net, trainningData]` with only several samples.

---

Seems the problem is about `NetEncoder[{"Image", {100, 35}]`, change the ImageDimensions will reproduce the error. ImageDimensions in NetEncoder should be the same[35,35]?

OK in `trained = NetTrain[net, MapAt[Import@# &, trainingData, {All, 1}]]`

Bug?
[image]

Comment: Could you try [this example](https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/neural-networks/out-of-core-image-classification.html?product=mathematica) and see if it works?

Comment: @xslittlegrass OK, in this official example...

Comment: @xslittlegrass seems a bug.