# How can I speed up import images into memory and make training more efficient

Tags: import, image, machine-learning

My memory is 32GB, windows 10, cpu 7700k, GTX1080

50k images[400MB] cost me 30 minutes.
In a [CAPTCHA](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/143691/crack-captcha-using-deep-learning#) example, a simple net and in tunning hyper-parameters step with small values of MaxTrainingRounds, just 15 minutes training time consuming.

If Mathematica Kernel [crashes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/148714/6648), then I should import images again, it's very often[long term] and annoying.

So, I can DumpSave, too many disk memory costs, acceptable.

Can I speed up the import this images for purpose of training network?

Any other methods to make the whole thing efficient?
`wdx, readlist as txt?`

Comment: Did you try to store your images in one multipage file, like tif?  I guess, reading of the one big file is faster for traditional hard drives.
I've tried such tif's up to 2GB with 20k frames, the import time is ~ 1min.

Comment: You can refer my question [How to use Mathematica to train a network Using out of core classification?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/142135/how-to-use-mathematica-to-train-a-network-using-out-of-core-classification) And how do to [generate a .h5 file](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/146295/15961)

Comment: @partida Hi, There is a bug in partida ... see 
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148714/nettrain-always-crashes-in-out-of-core-training-with-netencoder-setting

Comment: @Rom38 hi, that's fast, what's your images' dimension? 100*100 or 300*300?

Comment: @HyperGroups, they are from 288*288 to 768*512. But of course, high-res is shorter..